YOLOv8 Transfer Learning: Loss of Pretrained Weights After Freezing Layers
After training, the model accurately predicts cardboard boxes, but it fails to detect any other objects that it used to identify before the training. It seems that the pretrained weights have been overwritten or lost. My goal is to retain the ability to detect other objects while fine-tuning the model specifically for cardboard boxes.
I've sourced a properly labeled dataset from Roboflow.
https://universe.roboflow.com/dataset-t7hz7/cardboard-eupc8
Why is the model losing its ability to detect other objects after training, even though I’ve frozen the initial 10 layers? How can I maintain the original object detection capabilities from YoloV8 while focusing on identifying cardboard boxes?
Code:
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

    
model.train(
    data='/Users/shubhamb/IdeaProjects/transfer-learning/data/data.yaml',
    epochs=25,
    imgsz=416,
    freeze=10,
    plots=True,
    #device="mps",
    name="custom_yolov8_model"
)


Looks like it is going through catastrophic forgetting.
Found the reason at:
https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/5908#issuecomment-1776281564

I kindly suggest you post a self-answer quoting the linked source, in order for this to be of usefulness to others in the future, too.
